# Forces Problem from Halliday, Resnick and Krane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

To my knowledge, the net force on $m_1$ is $T - m_1 \cdot g \cdot \sin(\theta_1) = m_1 \cdot a$ assuming that the block accelerates up the incline. However, the solutions manual states that the acceleration is given by $m_1 \cdot a = g\cdot m_1 \cdot \sin(\theta_1) - T$ in that same situation.

I have been at this for half an hour now and can't understand how acceleration is opposite in direction to the tension force when moving up the incline. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're choosing the positive coordinate axis to be up the slope, while the solution is choosing the positive axis down the slope. The motion will be the same regardless of how one chooses coordinates (as it must be).

Comment: The choice of coordinate axis changes the acceleration overall, though. Specifically, with the HRK solution I get $(m_1)\cdot (\sin \theta_1) - m_2 \cdot \sin(\theta_2)$ in the numerator, whereas I get the reverse in the numerator with my solution. This changes the answer.

Comment: All that does is change the sign of the acceleration, which is exactly what you would expect if you flip the direction of the axis!

Comment: Okay, that part makes sense so thanks. However, if the positive axis was down the slope, wouldn't the acceleration be $-m_1 \cdot a$?

Comment: The notation is sloppy. The $a$ there should really be something like $a_x$, i.e., the $x$-component of the vector $\vec{a}$. Since it's a component of a vector, and not just a magnitude, it has a sign corresponding to its direction. The sign of $a_x$ will change depending on which direction is taken to be the $+x$-axis, and there's no need to put in the additional minus sign by hand.